# Radio Button checked not changing

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

I'm having an odd issue with a form I am working with. I have the following:

```
<?php 
    $show = ' checked ';
    $hide = ' ';

    /* Some logic to swap the checked here */
?>
<label class="radio-inline" for="show">Show</label>
<input type="radio" id="show" name="show" value="1" {{ $show }} />
<label class="radio-inline" for="hide">Hide</label>
<input type="radio"  id="hide" name="show" value="0" {{ $hide }} />
```

This code is loaded in a form that shows up in an Ajax modal. The initial state for $show works and it's set to `checked`. However, when I click on Hide, the radio swaps but the attribute does not change to checked, and `$show` stays on checked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you observing this value? In the browser inspector?

Answer (score 1):

Name of the radio options must be the same.

```
<input type="radio" id="show" name="visibility" value="1" {{ $show }} />
<input type="radio"  id="hide" name="visibility" value="0" {{ $hide }} />
```

Comment: My mistake, in my original code they are the same, forgot to edit it here. Edited the code above now